# Steam Authentication with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, steam

I am using Symfony framework in my project and now I am trying to add Steam Authentication to my project, so I could use Steam account informations in my project. Earlier is used only plain PHP, no frameworks and I found this https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication and it worked well, but I am not sure that can I use it with Symfony? I mean, how to include it in my controller? Or is there another way to Steam Authenticate with Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom authenticator for this. This way, you can easily adapt it into the current Symfony security system. Take a look at the documentation for this at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you could, as many others already have, one such example for Symfony2 is here: https://github.com/SirWaddles/SteamAuthBundle :) good luck.